# Any possibility for simplified punctuation in direct speech?

Tags: punctuation, commas, quotations, direct-speech, quotation-marks

Not sure I'm asking about direct speech here, though. Consider the sentence:

> And then I thought, why do I even need this?

I believe I run into sentences like this occasionally. The correct way would likely be:

> And then I thought, "Why do I even need this?"

Or maybe with colon?

> And then I thought: "Why do I even need this?"

To be precise, can I not capitalize first letter of direct speech? Can I omit quotes? Should I use comma or colon?

Also, I've run into [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/15271/how-to-say-the-answer-to-your-question-is-shortly/15289) one of these days. Can I write:

> To answer your question, no.
>   The answer to your question is, no.

Or

> To answer your question, no, I don't think so.
>   The answer to your question is, no, I don't think so.

By the way, as you can see, the respondent there has [omitted](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/15289/1812) the quotes

> To answer your question: No.

Comment: It depends on your context, what is your context? A novel? An online chat room?

Comment: @Lambie Not a novel. Chat rooms... That's probably taking it too far. Forums, Q&A sites, blogs, places where you can use informal speech. Where you write more than one sentence at a time.

Comment: There are no rules for chat rooms. People write whatever they want. If they do not want to use punctuation, that's fine.

Comment: @Lambie But I'm not talking about chat rooms here. For example, the other user on this site [omitted quotes](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/15289/1812) in his answer. Is this not governed by any rules? Or maybe not rules, but some conventions. Like, what punctuation people usually use under such circumstances?

Comment: Ok, what did I say above?? I said it depends on your context. You talk about the correct way. Well, the correct way is only used in places where speech is properly punctuated. Where is speech punctuated? In newspaper articles when a reporter is quoting a person. Or in other print publications when a person is being quoted. In that sense, you would get: "And then I thought, 'Why do I even need this?' "  The double quotes are for the person being quoted and the single quotes are for the quote within a quote.

Comment: @Lambie Let's talk about about the incorrect way :) Like, what is okay for native speakers on this site. For instance, in [the other thread](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/131044/cleft-sentences-with-it#comment263641_131044) you said: "Here we would say: And that's what you're supposed to provide." Why did you not use quotation marks?

Comment: Because the quotes just mean straight speech there. I was trying to show spoken language, real speech. And there was no quote within a quote.