# Cleft sentences with "it"

Tags: cleft-constructions

I've got a bit technical example. But hopefully, you don't need to know the topic. I was discussing design of, say, an application (or plugin, to be more specific). What I said was:

> Generally, you have a form, and file input is just one of the fields. With your plugin, you've got file input and it's it you're supposed to provide with information which extra fields to pass. And it's it that is responsible for submitting the form.

The part I'm concerned about is "it's it". Is that okay?

**UPD** By second "it" I mean "plugin" or "file input". Which can be used more or less interchangeably here. And the point is to put emphasis on the file input/plugin part.

Where is this coming from? Let's consider [this sentence](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/it-was-he-him-who-told-you.780557/) (taken from a book, according to thread starter):

> It was he who told you I'd be here!

So, I'm trying to follow the pattern, which results in: "...it's it that..." Is that wrong?

If I wouldn't be concerned about emphasis, I'd say:

> You're supposed to provide plugin with information as to which extra fields to pass. It's also responsible for submitting the form.

Comment: "It's it you're" doesn't make sense.  What are you trying to say?

Comment: In English, this is called deictics and the use of deictic pronouns. When talking, if you refer back to a thing in your speech, you should use **this** or **that** or ***this is what*** or that's what and not it. /it/ is OK grammatically speaking but not really conversationally speaking. Here we would say: And ***that's what*** you're supposed to provide.

Comment: As Lambie says, use *that* (or *this*) rather than *it*; and I would recommend using *which* rather than *that* for the relative clause, so you don't get tangled up (or tangle your reader up) with multiple *thats*: "...it is that which you're supposed to provide", "...it's that which is responsible".

Comment: @Andrew If I say, "... and it's the plugin, that you're supposed to provide with information which extra fields to pass." Does it make it clear? That is, you're supposed to provide plugin with some information. But I want to put emphasis on the plugin part.

Comment: @x-yuri maybe "it's **what** you are supposed to provide with information about which fields to pass"

Comment: @x-yuri  By the way "It's It" is the name of an old ice cream sandwich brand: https://www.itsiticecream.com/ .   So it's not necessarily *wrong*, as long as you use it to mean, "it/this is the thing you want".

Comment: Let's take [this sentence](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/it-was-he-him-who-told-you.780557/): "It was he who told you I'd be here!" In my case it would turn into: "...it's the plugin that..." Or maybe even into: "...it's it that..." Why is that wrong? By the way, plugin and file input can be used more or less interchangeably here. Sorry for telling it this late. And let me reiterate, I need emphasis on the plugin/file input part. Generally, file input is just one of the form's fields. But with this plugin file input is basically in control of everything.

Answer (score 1):

> With your plugin, you've got file input and you're supposed to provide **it** with information **as to** which extra fields to pass. And that is responsible for submitting the form.

is much simpler. I removed both of the `it's it`s and added another `it` in the first sentence. I also added `as to`, because your first sentence didn't make sense without it (even with the `it's it`). Your second sentence was too verbose, by simply removing the `it's it` it still makes sense.

Your use of `it's it` is grammatically OK but very awkward. The comments have better info on this than I do.

Comment: Take a look at [my comment](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/131044/cleft-sentences-with-it?noredirect=1#comment263671_131044), please. Your phrasing lacks emphasis on the file input/plugin part.

Comment: @x-yuri "it" and "that" both refer back to "file input". I don't know what extra emphasis you want to add - you give it information, it is responsible for submitting the form. In your linked comment, "He told you I'd be here" IMO puts just as much emphasis on "he" as "It is he" without sounding obtuse. I don't honestly see a put in making the sentence any more complex than it needs to be. If you can clarify a bit on why mine doesn't have the proper emphasis, I can help you more.

Comment: What Wikipedia says: "Clefts typically put a particular constituent into focus." And one of the examples: "It's Joey we're looking for." Does the sentence conveys the same meaning for you as: "We're looking for Joey"? Except for being more complex (or maybe rather uncommon)? But isn't saying something not the way people usually say it is a way to put emphasis? As to your phrasing, what's in it that puts emphasis?

Comment: @x-yuri OK, that makes sense. Thank you for the clarification. I'll get back to you :)